# Python bindings for VLC

Tags: python, windows, vlc

I am on Windows, and I wish to use Python Bindings for VLC. I've already downloaded the module from https://github.com/geoffsalmon/vlc-python , and did as per the read me. But, still I'm stuck at importing the module. The error looks like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
  import vlc
  File "c:\python27\python-vlc-1.1.2\vlc.py", line 173, in <module>
  dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "c:\python27\python-vlc-1.1.2\vlc.py", line 150, in find_lib
  dll = ctypes.CDLL('libvlc.dll')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
  self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
  WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Any Solution on where to place the module ? My main aim is to play MP3 audio files through vlc, which would be part of some other activity.

Comment: From the README: `On win32, the simplest way is to put the vlc.py file in the same
directory as the libvlc.dll file (standard location:
c:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC ).` Have you done this?

Comment: Yes, I did that, copied the compiled version too. @wilbur

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem.
It turns out for me if you have 64bit python, you need 64bit vlc player.
If you have 32bit python, you need 32bit vlc player.

Hope that works for you too.

Comment: Great! But, how do I get a 64bit vlc player code? I have the `vlc.py` file, which is pure Python and it works with my Python2 but not with my Python3. Can you please take a look at my question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086279/vlc-and-python-architecture-comatibility-issue

Answer (score 0):

I paired with 64bit I solved as follows. Of course

```
# first set the environment which is required from vlc.py
import os
os.environ['PYTHON_VLC_MODULE_PATH'] = """C:\Program Files\VideoLan"""
os.environ['PYTHON_VLC_LIB_PATH'] = """C:\Program Files\VideoLan\VLC\libvlc.dll"""
# now you can import vlc
import vlc
```