# How to install 64-bit vlc library for 64-bit python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, vlc

I've tried `python -m pip install python-vlc` with the sole installed version of python 3.6 64-bit, yet it seemed to have installed the 32-bit version of the `vlc` library as I've experienced [this very issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35487490/7032856), which has an accepted solution of installing the library with a matching architecture type to that of python's. However, it isn't explicitly stated on how to do that.

How can I specifically install 64-bit `vlc` library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it should be compatible. As long as the Architecture of your Python and VLC installations are the same. There is no destinct version of python-vlc. So if you want to target both Architectures, you would have to use both the x86 and x64 version of Python

Comment: By, VLC installation you don't, by any means, mean the actual VLC player, right? Because I tried using vlc with a 64-bit version of python and ended up seemingly installing 32-bit.

Comment: Yes, I actually mean it, you have to make sure both Python and VLC use the same architecture.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with 64-bit VLC _Player_, thanks a lot.