# LibVLC - Disabled popup video player

Tags: python

I'm trying to use libVLC in a Python program to play an online live stream.
The program passes .m3u8 link to libVLC, which works fine.

When the stream starts, it opens a window titled VLC (Direct3D11 output).
However, I only want the audio to play, not the video to show. This is the usual behaviour with a .mp3 file for example.

In short: **how can I disable the video output of libVLC, to have it play just the audio of a live stream, with no window?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know libVLC very well, but I had a similar problem with the [python-vlc module](https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/).
In my case, I wanted to play the audio of a youtube video/stream.
I modified the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354232/how-to-stream-audio-from-a-youtube-url-in-python-without-download) by adding the `--no-video` argument when instantiating the vlc object.
This is basically a general VLC command line argument to suppress video output.
Maybe there is a similar option to add this in libVLC?
Below the code, just for reference:

```py
import pafy
import vlc

url = "YOURVIDEOURL"
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
playurl = best.url

Instance = vlc.Instance("--no-video") #This did the trick
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new(playurl)
Media.get_mrl()

player.set_media(Media)
player.play()

input()
```