# How to stream audio from a Youtube URL in Python (without download) on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, audio, youtube, stream

I am trying to stream youtube audio using Python on Windows 10.  I found a StackOverflow question that's asking the [same exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354232/how-to-stream-audio-from-a-youtube-url-in-python-without-download); but leads to a dead end when using Windows.

If I use the script below using Python 2.7 (32bit) on Windows, I get the error:  **"WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found"**.

I am open to any solution that doesn't involve launching a bulky GUI application such as a web browser.  I'm looking for a very lightweight audio player (and respective Python code) to playback YouTube audio from a URL.  The below script "should" work, but doesn't on Windows.

```python
import pafy
import vlc
import time

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PK5vAr5u6Xo"
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
playurl = best.url

Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new(playurl)
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
duration = player.get_length() / 1000
player.play()
time.sleep(duration)
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem too!

Comment: @CheetSheatOverlode Please see the answer to this question.  It turned out I just needed to install the Windows VLC installer for Windows.  After i did that, the depenency was satisfied.

Comment: I tried that too, shortly after my comment on this. It worked, as it did for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install a normal Windows VLC application for the VLC module to use.  The Python VLC module doesn't install the dependencies needed for playback.

[Download Windows VLC installer here](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html)