# How can I make python play audio from a youtube vid for my program?

Tags: python, audio, mp3

So at the moment I have an mp3 file in my programs directory, and I use the following code to play it:

```html
from pygame import mixer  # Load the popular external library

file = 'LinusAndLucy.mp3'
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(file)
mixer.music.play()
```

It works fine, but I don't want to be transfering my python file around to other computers with the mp3 file, I would rather it streams the audio directly from a youtube url that I specify.

Is this possible? I have read similar questions to this on here and none seem to do the trick ([specifically this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354232/how-to-stream-audio-from-a-youtube-url-in-python-without-download))

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) (`pip install youtube-dl`).

See the [documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl) about embedding for details.

You'll end up with something like this:

```
import youtube_dl

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'
filename = '/tmp/file.mp3'  # where do you want to save the file?

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': filename,
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192'
        }]
    }
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
```

After which, you can play the downloaded file with pygame.

Comment: Ok so I have added this code (thanks! :) :) ), however the file downloads successfully, and the program closes. It doesn't continue on and play the song etc etc